# Relative path to store log files with Essential.Diagnostics

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, logging

I am using System.Diagnostics + [Essential.Diagnostics](http://essentialdiagnostics.codeplex.com/) for my logger in my ASP.NET MVC 3 app. Here is my web.config:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <sources>
        <source name="requests" switchValue="All">
            <listeners>
                <remove name="default" />
                <add name="rollingxml" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
        <add name="rollingxml"
            type="Essential.Diagnostics.RollingXmlTraceListener, Essential.Diagnostics"
            initializeData="e:\myapi\v2\App_Data\Logfiles\{ApplicationName}-{LocalDateTime:yyyy-MM-dd}.svclog"
        />
    </sharedListeners>
</system.diagnostics>
```

As you can see, the folder path to store the log files are hardcoded as `e:\myapi\v2\App_Data\Logfiles\`.

I want to put the log files into my app's app_data folder, but since the app is put in different locations in my dev PC, the staging server, and the main server, I need to put relative path in the `initializeData`. Something like `.\App_Data\Logfiles\`.

I have tried `.\App_Data\Logfiles\` but it went to `c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\App_Data\Logfiles\`.

Is it possible to point to my app folder using relative path with Essential.Diagnostics?

Comment: I am not familiar with Essential.Diagnostics but in log4net you can use an environment variable in the configuration to indicate the path. Does Essential.Diagnostics support environment variables in the path?

Comment: @HectorCorrea I don't think it has that feature, but I'm also not familiar with it.

Answer (score 2):

Use this token: {AppData}

```
<sharedListener>

<add name="rollingfile" 
             type="Essential.Diagnostics.RollingFileTraceListener, Essential.Diagnostics" 
             initializeData="{AppData}\{ApplicationName}-{DateTime:yyyy-MM-dd}.log" 
             convertWriteToEvent="true"></add>
<sharedListener>
```

ref: https://essentialdiagnostics.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=RollingFileTraceListener&referringTitle=Documentation